# In maven pom.xml, how to include another xml into pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven, xinclude

I have a `pom.xml` file in my maven (java) project.
I have two other xml files containing different set of project dependencies and plugins.
I want to include one out of the two other xml files into my `pom.xml` file.
I see that there are suggestions to use `xinclude`, but I can't figure out how to make use of that in my `pom.xml` file.

Following is the content of my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="pom-config2.xml" parse="xml"/>
</document>
```

example `pom-config1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mygroup.g1</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectn</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>processor</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

example `pom-config2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mygroup.g1</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectn</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>processor</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I get
`Project build error: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.Java(0)` .

How do I properly include that other xml into the maven project's pom.xml?

Comment: Don't do this. I am comared your two version's pom.xml.  If you just want skipping test, use command `mvn clean package -DskipTests` or `mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, Reference https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: The dependencies listed in the example files are just examples. Not necessarily to indicate the purpose as testing or skipping.

Comment: The question is coming up why do you have different sets of dependencies? Apart from that I see several plugins which are old you should use most recent versions of the plugins (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) and no you should not do this via xml include (apart from that it will not work either)... ?

Comment: Please describe in detail your problem and what kind of issue/intention you want to solve...

Comment: @khmarbaise Hope this explains the purpose/intension: "I want to include one out of the two other xml files into my pom.xml file."
Issue is, I'm unable to figure out how to achieve that. I have tried XInclude, but that gives me the error `Project build error: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.Java(0) ` . 
All of these are in the question. Wondering if example files appearing more prominent than my effort and problem stated.

Comment: I know what an include in xml means, but that does not explain the idea behind it? Why are doing so and what is need to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include other XML files into the `pom.xml` file.

I guess your underlying problem is different. If you asked about the original problem (like how to manage different sets of dependency versions etc.), then we might figure out a solution for you.